# Validate Max Login Attempts

Tags: c#

I'm just adding a method to my login process in which I want to give the user 5 login attempts (ie incorrect password), then prevent the user from attempting to login again for say 30 minutes since the last failed attempt.
(Obviously they could fail login several times during the day)

So I've created a new simple table (UserAttempts):

```
Id
UserId
LoginDateTime
```

But I'm struggling to how to do the logic with this?

```
User user = uw.User.FindByUser(userName);

if (user != null)
{
    var loginAttempts = user.UserAttempts.Where(a => a.LoginDateTime.Date == DateTime.Today);
    if (loginAttempts.Any())
    {
        //Logic here to say has the user attempted to login more than 5 times within the last 30 mins?
        //If true return null
        //Else return user.
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the number of attempts within the last 30 minutes; the easiest way to do that is to check for those with an attempt time greater than 30 minutes ago:

```
.Where(a.LoginDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30))
```

Then you want to know the count; and `Count` also takes a predicate so:

```
if (user.UserAttempts.Count(a.LoginDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30)) > 5)
{
   //hacker!!!
}
```

You don't want to check for dates where `Date` is `DateTime.Today` because you would have a window when the date changes that allows for more attempts. It also doesn't save any filtering time since you have to look at all the dates regardless; might as well compare against the actual time you care about.

While your code doesn't reflect it; you also mention "locking out" the user for 30 minutes. To do that I would probably just set a flag indicating the lockout status and check if enough time has passed since the last attempt (using an `OrderBy` or `Max` on the `LoginDateTime`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
var recentThreshold = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
int recentAttempts = user.UserAttempts
                         .Count(a => a.CreatedDate > recentThreshold);
if (recentAttempts > 5)
    blockUser();
else
    warnUser();
```

`recentThreshold` is the "cutoff point", events before which you're not interested in. We can just use `Count` to find how many login events happened after this threshold.

Note that we don't filter by today's events (`DateTime.Today`), as you'd really still like to be aware of people who tried to login 4 times at 23:59, then again at 00:00.

Comment: No point in doing a Where then a Count; Count takes a predicate, also `.Date` will remove time information

Comment: _a.CreatedDate.Date_ returns just the date with time missing.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I'd forgotten `CreatedDate` would probably be a `DateTime` itself.

Comment: I'm not even sure where `CreatedDate` comes from given the table at the start; but he was using it in his attempt...

Answer (score 1):

Most "count-solutions" above will give one more try after LESS than 30 minutes. And you want to "lock the account out" for 30 minutes after the last failed attempt?

*Assume a user tries to login and fail 3 times, then wait 15 minutes and tries 3 times again and fail: then he/she will not be locked out for 30 minutes, but only 15 minutes (until the first 3 attempts "timeout").*

We need to wait 30 minutes after the LAST failed attempt.

```
var lastFailedAttempt = user.UserAttempts.OrderbyDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

if (lastFailedAttempt == null || lastFailedAttempt.CreatedDate.AddMinutes(30) < DateTime.Now) //No attempts have been made or the last one was more than 30 minutes ago
  return user;

return user.UserAttempts.Count(a => a.CreatedDate > lastFailedAttempt.CreatedDate.AddMinutes(-30)) <= 5 ? user : null; //Check if there are more than 5 attempts 30 minutes before the last failed
```

This till not "extend" the timeout if one retries every 29 minutes. If you want to do that, perhaps it is simpler to save "LockedOutUntil" datetime in the database.

Answer (score -2):

```
var loginAttempts = user.UserAttempts.Where(a => a.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

Change this LINQ-u query to get only login attempts from recent 30 minutes and then execute count() function on this query.

I don't understand what is your problem exactly because that seems to be easy.

Comment: This is telling the OP "solve your problem by solving your problem". Not helpful.